# How to do a Unity drop and drag unit

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have my prefabs for my characters but I'm lost wondering how am I able to do a drop-able unit like Clash Of Clans. I'm almost done with the game i'm making does anyone have an idea or suggestion to do it? source code or tutorial will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by drop-able unit? Can you give some details.Do you mean dropping some troops somewhere on the map?

Answer (score 0):

just like items in an inventory

instantiate your prefab on touch.

you can either iterate through a loop and keep instantiating until your out of troops,

or

you can use a bool and an update method, to spawn one unit at your touch/mouse down,
move its position to mouse/touch position in update, as long as still touching,
finally in your mouse/touch up you stop updating his position manual and release him.

if you would like some help with the code for either implementation let me know!